# Failed to start ubuntu live CD installer

Tags: lenovo, usb-installation

[image: screenshot]

I am unable to try/install Ubuntu 22.04 using USB.
I use the guideline provided by Ubuntu official website, the USB installer is created using balenaEtcher. I try to boot using the way provided by Lenovo official website (restart and press F12 while having USB plugged in).
My laptop is Lenovo 310-14IKB Laptop (ideapad) - Type 80TU, Windows 10.

I tried turning off fast startup/ changing boot mode to legacy/changing boot priority from UEFI to legacy/disabling safe booting mode, but none of them works.

Comment: Please edit your original question to tell us more: Did you check the sha256sum of the iso file (that it was downloaded correctly)? What tool did you use to create the USB installer drive? How did you try to boot into the USB drive? - I see 'noveau' in the output list. It indicates that there is an nvidia graphics chip/card, and I suggest that you try booting with the **boot option `nomodeset`**. There is detailed help about it at [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808). If that works, you can install a proprietary nvidia graphics driver later on.

Comment: Your edits to the original question indicate that you are doing things correctly. You might check the sha256sum too (check versus the published value), but I am more convinced now, that you have a graphics problem, so please try booting with `nomodeset` (or simply select 'Ubuntu (safe graphics)' in the grub menu.

Comment: If still no luck, we need new ideas to test, for example, have you tested with the previous but still supported LTS version [Ubuntu 20.04.4](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.4/)?

Comment: Thank you everyone!!!!!!! I made it!

Comment: Congratulations, and welcome back, if you have other questions in the future :-)

Comment: Sure, really thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

Hope my little experience can help anyone using Lenovo laptop in future.

I change to using Rufus to create the USB using the GPT option. I disabled the fast startup option but didn't disable the safe booting option. Then I boot the laptop using NOVO button (option 2 in Lenovo official guidelines) instead of using legacy bootmode. And lastly add in the **nomodeset** option

Comment: I have Dell Latitude E6530.  I followed using Rufus v 3.20, GPT partition scheme, UEFI (non CSM) target system.  Then, boot in UEFI mode (safe graphics) option.  And finally! No black screen and I can progress the Ubuntu 22.04 installation.

Answer (score 0):

dont use

> Try install bla bla

use

> Safe GUI bla bla

Answer (score 0):

I was firing the USB from terminal command line and I was getting this error. When I switched to [BalenaEtcher](https://etcher.balena.io/), in addition to change the USB port and sticker. it worked like a charm!