# Why Does a burned iso of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS take about 10 Minutes to load and start Ubuntu Live CD Installer?

Tags: system-installation, 22.04

Does anyone know why it takes a while for an iso image of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS burned to disc to load to the installer/live session? I did a screen record below with timestamp sped up where when booting from disc (DVD-R DL), it will fail similar to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1405697/1151435), and eventually load. IS this common now with burned physical media? Is it not optimized for DVD? Is it because I used ImgBurn to burn iso to disc? I only ask since the system I was booting on did not have available USB ports and I tried my luck with the disc drive.

[image]

Comment: The boot media is intended for be *flash* media for releases beyond 20.04, as the media validation (*reading every sector of optical media*) is very slow). Only releases up to 20.04 were *optimized* for *optical* media; why are you using the *outdated* media???